# error: invalid resource type 'attr' for parent of style

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading my Android project to Studio 3.0.1 and Gradle 3.0 I am facing an issue during the build:

```
MAFLogonUI-3.15.6.aar\\46f903e9d58266c453b893b9caa03deb\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":456,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":32855,"endLine":459,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":33105}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

I believe the issue is due to the issue referenced here [Android help](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#aapt2)
where they state that he @ symbol is suppsed to be omitted when referring to "android". And indeet the generated values.xml file contains:

```
<style name="SapUexTextAppearance.SlidingTabActive" parent="@android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"> ...
```

But as this comes from a library that I have included in my build I dunno if I have any control over this. Is there a way to prevent the @ symbols in the generated res/values/value.xml? or will I need an upgrade of my lib?

In the meantime I have disabled AAPT2...

Answer (score 10):

Just change `@android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` to `@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium`. Starting from Gradle 3 style parents must be styles as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the "@" symbol. The problem is that they're using an attribute for a style's parent, while the parent should always be a style as well. 
Since the incorrect code comes from a library, you can try overriding the style in your resources, but it would be ideal if the owners of the library fixed that XML file instead.