# AAPT: error: invalid resource type 'attr' for parent of style, after updating gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt, aapt2

After upgrading from Gradle wrapper 4.4.1 to 6.1.1, along with going from Android build tools 2.3.0 to 4.0.0, builds all of a sudden fail with the following error:

```
res/values/treeview_styles.xml:3:5-6:13: AAPT: error: invalid resource type 'attr' for parent of style.
```

The resource file in question looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style parent="@android:attr/listViewStyle" name="treeViewListStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/divider</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**What is happening here, and how can I fix this?**

---

Background information: The code comes from [a tree list view control](https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android) I am using in my app. I have simply copied the source tree into mine so that I could make some modifications.

The [developer reference for `android.R.attr`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#listViewStyle) mentions `listViewStyle`, stating it has been available since API 1, so I am wondering if it is a reference to that. On the other hand, my app uses `appcompat-v7`, and in my local SDK tree at `extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml` I indeed found:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu" parent="">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp</item>
</style>
```

That looks as if `android:listViewStyle` is just an alias for `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu`. Indeed, using `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu` compiles and the UI looks OK at first glance.

Note that the toolchain upgrade included switching from AAPT to AAPT2. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47535494/2703209) and its answers, AAPT2 is stricter about some things than its predecessor. In particular, parents of styles must be styles as well. That would at least explain the error message, we just need to hunt down the correct resource name.

Comment: They're right, that isn't a valid parent (and never has been). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The code is from https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android, a tree list view I am using in my app (I’ve copied the whole source tree into mine, no JAR or anything). At https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#listViewStyle I am seeing `listViewStyle`, which has been around since API 4. Could it be a reference to that? If so, how do I reference that resource correctly? (And how come this worked on older toolchains?)

Comment: I found something in appcompat-v7 (`$ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml`), which the app uses and which in style `Base.Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu` has `<item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu</item>`. Apparently that’s where it comes from. If in my sources I replace `@android:attr/listViewStyle` with `Widget.AppCompat.ListView.Menu`, the code compiles and the list view looks OK at first glance. Not sure if that is the right way to solve this, though,.

Comment: The problem is `parent="@android:attr/listViewStyle"`, so replacing that with an actual parent theme, and not something from an attribute, would indeed fix it. What theme are you using?

Comment: `AppBaseTheme` on API 21+, `Theme.AppCompat` on lower levels.

Answer (score 0):

[ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) wrote:

*The problem is parent=`"@android:attr/listViewStyle"`, so replacing that with an actual parent theme, and not something from an attribute, would indeed fix it. What theme are you using?*

In addition i found that:

[Behavior changes when using AAPT2](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#aapt2_changes):

> Additionally, when declaring a  element, its parent must also
> be a style resource type. Otherwise, you get an error similar to the
> following:

```
Error: (...) invalid resource type 'attr' for parent of style
```